# How to conditionally run a script in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

Currently, My react start script is as follows : `env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts start`. I want to run some test script before this and if that fails do not run the above.
I have tried `"start": "node src/test/test.js --check . && env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts start"` but when there is some error thrown in my test.js(which is handled using `try-catch`), the start script still runs which I don't want it to.

Comment: The `test.js` script needs to return a non-zero exit code. Then the `&&` will prevent the `env-cmd` from running. https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please check the link in the comment?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It worked. Thanks. Please add your answer I'll accept.